# Compare column values by skipping null values?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

### SQL statement one:

```sql
select glaccountid,debit,credit 
from transactionentries 
where glaccountid in (15376);
```

Above statement returns output below:

```
+------------------------------+
| glaccountid | debit | credit |
+------------------------------+
|  15376      |  1584 |  null  |
+------------------------------+
|  15376      |  null | 1400   |
+------------------------------+
```

SQL statement two:

```sql
select glaccountid,debit,credit 
from transactionentries 
where glaccountid in (15374);
```

Above statement returns result below:

```
+------------------------------+
| glaccountid | debit | credit |
+------------------------------+
|  15374      |  null | 1584   |
+------------------------------+
|  15374      | 14000 | null   |
+------------------------------+
```

What I am trying is to write a query that returns transaction entries where the debit value of `15376` is not equal to the credit value of `15374` and vice verse by ignoring columns with NULL values.

### What I've already tried:

```
SELECT cpo.glaccountid cpo,cpo.debit,cpo.credit,ba.glaccountid branch, ba.debit,ba.credit 
  FROM transactionentries cpo 
 INNER JOIN transactionentries ba 
    ON cpo.transactionid = ba.transactionid
 WHERE cpo.glaccountid = 15374 
   AND ba.glaccountid = 15376 
   AND (cpo.debit <> ba.credit OR ba.debit <> cpo.credit);
```

### Expected output:

```
+------------------------------+
| glaccountid | debit | credit |
+------------------------------+
|  15374      |  14000 |  null |
+------------------------------+
|  15376      |  null | 1400   |
+------------------------------+
```

Answer (score 1):

You can not compare `null` as if it was a value, because `null` in Oracle is meant to be "no information", and not a value. You may find many good answers about this.

About your query, if you want to only consider records with both `not null` values, this can be a self-explanatory way to edit your `where` contition:

```
(
  (cpo.debit <> ba.credit and cpo.debit is not null and ba.credit is not null)
or
  (ba.debit <> cpo.credit and ba.debit is not null and cpo.credit is not null)
)
```

You may edit it in different ways; this is the most readableI can think.

Comment: You make a join based on `transactionid` , but you don't post it, so the expected result is not that useful. Can you please post all relevant data?

Comment: Also, in the expected output, where are debit and credit from? Which occurrence of the table?